# How to implement two rating bars in one fragment

Tags: android

Here I am trying to implement two rating bars ratingbar1 and ratingbar2,but error says only one onRatingChanged can be called,Then How can I implement ratingbar2 too.

Although when I am trying to implement only ratingbar1,my code is working fine.

Please tell me how to implement onRatingChanged method of ratingbar2 ?

```
public class FragmentT12 extends Fragment implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener
    {
        View view;
        TextView textbox1,textbox2;
        RatingBar ratingbar1,ratingbar2;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_t12,container,false);
            textbox1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textbox1);
            textbox2=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textbox2);
            ratingbar1=(RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar1);
            ratingbar2=(RatingBar)view.findViewById(R.id.ratingbar2);
            ratingbar1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
            ratingbar2.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(this);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingbar1, float rating, boolean fromUser)
        {
            float i;
            i=ratingbar1.getRating();

            if(i==1.0)
            {textbox1.setText("Strongly Disagree");
            textbox1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));
                textbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
            }

            else if(i==2.0)
            {textbox1.setText("Disagree");
                textbox1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#996600"));
                textbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

            else if(i==3.0)
            {textbox1.setText("Neither Agree Nor Disagree");
                textbox1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006666"));
                textbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

            else if(i==4.0)
            {textbox1.setText("Agree");
                textbox1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0033cc"));
                textbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

            else if(i==5.0)
            {textbox1.setText("Strongly Agree");
                textbox1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#009933"));
                textbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

        }

        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingbar2, float rating, boolean fromUser)**ERROR IS HERE
        {
            float i;
            i=ratingbar2.getRating();

            if(i==1.0)
            {textbox2.setText("Strongly Disagree");
                textbox2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));
                textbox2.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
            }

            else if(i==2.0)
            {textbox2.setText("Disagree");
                textbox2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#996600"));
                textbox2.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

            else if(i==3.0)
            {textbox2.setText("Neither Agree Nor Disagree");
                textbox2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006666"));
                textbox2.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

            else if(i==4.0)
            {textbox2.setText("Agree");
                textbox2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0033cc"));
                textbox2.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

            else if(i==5.0)
            {textbox2.setText("Strongly Agree");
                textbox2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#009933"));
                textbox2.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);}

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should only use one onRatingChanged method and check which ratingbar is calling it,using the ratingBar in the parameters :

```
@Override
public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingbar, float rating, boolean fromUser){
if(ratingbar== ratingbar1){
//code for ratingbar 1 
}
else if (ratingbar == ratingbar2){
//code for ratingbar 2
}   
    }
```